# How do i add shadow effect onto a section divider?

Tags: html, css, sections

I'm using clip-path to create this section divider. I wanted to add a shadow effect on the 6 sides of this section. I tried box shadow but it couldn't show the shadow on the sides of the section divider. The image below is the shadow effect that i wanted to create on my section divider.
[image]

this is what i have tried to create the box shadow

```
<section style=" clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 black;margin-top: -10px;padding-bottom: 3rem;background-color: #ffffff;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use skew and both pseudo elements for this shape

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 15px);
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 black
}

.container::before {
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  clip-path: inset(0 15px 0 0);
}

.container::after {
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 15px);
}

body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```